# Productsum in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to calculate the formula below in one cell in Excel:

[image]

I don't see how to do so. Would anyone know?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array (confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) version of `PRODUCT`:

`=PRODUCT(1+A1:A10*B1:B10)`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In one cell you won't be able to calculate the 1+alpha*r, but you can create two columns: alpha, r, and the last which calculates 1+alpha_i*r_i, and finally you use [`PRODUCT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PRODUCT-function-8e6b5b24-90ee-4650-aeec-80982a0512ce):

[image: excel formula with product]

Comment: it is a good option if you want to compute the formula one time but I actually need a column made like C9 and my alphas vary